# PHP GET Show null while sending HTML Form request

Tags: php, html

While sending a form with special character. `PHP $_GET` Show null. what is the problem.

```
{"session_key":"5.dtZjcMnqIESiUg.1512120836.8-100003690804926",
```

this character is automatic encoded in URL_encoded in browser URL 
all my code was running well but now its not working.

URL in browser

```
%7B"session_key"%3A"5.dtZjcMnqIESiUg.1512120836.8-100003690804926"%2C
```

var dump result is null

```
array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(0) "" }
```

html form

```
<form method="get" action="login.php">
<input type="text" name="user">
<button name="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine for me. I copy/pasted your form, added the string above in the "user" field and submitted. I got the content just fine. I would rather ask what this is for and why you have a login form that uses GET and why it should accept a json string as user?

Comment: I also can't reproduce the problem. When I submit the form, `user=` is not missing from the front of it, and it shows up in the dumped data. `array(2) { ["user"]=> string(63) "{"session_key":"5.dtZjcMnqIESiUg.1512120836.8-100003690804926"," ["submit"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: i don't know why this happen only in server in local this code working fine.

Comment: But where does that partial json string come from? Why send it to begin with? I can't see any purpose of that form? If you give us some background we might be able to figure out what's going on or a better way.

Comment: this siring is copy paste  into input box manually. i am using https

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to $_GET['session_key'] not $_GET['submit']

Comment: The dulp appears to be of `$_GET` not `$_GET['submit']`